# Cart Item not remove or empty after checkout process in POS application in MERN. like await cartItems.findAndUpdate({ $set: { cartItems: [] } });

Tags: reactjs, mern, shopping-cart

i have created POS point of sale application in MERN that is working perfectly fine just there are two problems.

1. Cart Item not remove or empty after checkout process
   cart items remains same it didn't goes to zero
2. when i add product into cart it added into the cart as a new product but same product is also available in the cart. it should increment the value of product instead of adding it as a new product

i have a button in form where user can checkout after entering details and viewing the details

```
<Form layout="vertical" onFinish={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Item name="customerName" label="Customer Name">
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="customerNumber" label="Contact Number">
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="paymentMode" label="Payment Menthod">
            <Select>
              <Select.Option value="cash">Cash</Select.Option>
              <Select.Option value="card">Card</Select.Option>
            </Select>
          </Form.Item>
          <div className="bill-item">
            <h5>
              Sub Total : <b>{subTotal}</b>
            </h5>
            <h5>
              Total Tax : <b>{((subTotal / 100) * 0).toFixed(2)}</b>
            </h5>
            <h3>
              Grand Total{" "}
              <b>
                {Number(subTotal) + Number(((subTotal / 100) * 0).toFixed(2))}
              </b>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Generate Bill
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Form>
//handlesubmit
  const handleSubmit = async (value) => {
    try {
      const newObject = {
        ...value,
        cartItems,
        subTotal,
        tax: Number(((subTotal / 100) * 0).toFixed(2)),
        totalAmount: Number(
          Number(subTotal) + Number(((subTotal / 100) * 0).toFixed(2))
        ),
        userId: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth"))._id,
      };
      // console.log(newObject);
      await axios.post("/api/bills/add-bills", newObject);
      message.success("Bill Generated");
     /* here i am trying to empty the cartitems*/
 await cartItems.findAndUpdate({ $set: { cartItems: [] } });
      navigate("/bills");
    } catch (error) {
      message.error('something went wrong');
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: await cartItems.findAndUpdate({ $set: { cartItems: [] } }); here i am trying to flush the cart items after succesfull check but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution, i make another case

```
"CLEAR_CART": return { ...state, cartItems: [], };
```

then i pass the dispatch in my handlesubmit

```
 dispatch({ type: "CLEAR_CART", });
```

this clears the cart

```
//handlesubmit
  const handleSubmit = async (value) => {
    try {
      const newObject = {
        ...value,
        cartItems,
        subTotal,
        tax: Number(((subTotal / 100) * 0).toFixed(2)),
        totalAmount: Number(
          Number(subTotal) + Number(((subTotal / 100) * 0).toFixed(2))
        ),
        userId: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth"))._id,
      };
      // console.log(newObject);
      await axios.post("/api/bills/add-bills", newObject);
      message.success("Bill Generated");
      dispatch({
        type: "CLEAR_CART",
      });
      navigate("/bills");
    } catch (error) {
      message.error(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```